# Detecting width and height of picker view

Tags: ios, view, picker, bounds, cgrect

how do you detect the width and height of a picker view so that it can be placed appropriately? I'd like to use bounds, but can't figure out how to do it exactly. Thanks.

```
    durationPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,244,320,400)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Well in your case, the width is 320 and the height is 400, but for any `UIView`, you can get the width and height with `myview.frame.size.width` and `myview.frame.size.height`, respectively. so an nslog might be something like:

```
NSLog(@"durationPicker Frame Width: %i Height: %i", durationPicker.frame.size.width, durationPicker.frame.size.height);
```

If you want the bounds instead of the frame, substitute "bounds" where "frame" is in the above code.

Comment: Thanks for that, I know that I didn't add in that code for the width, and Apple makes it so that you can't adjust the height. I want to know how to place the picker view on the screen though. Ideally, I would like to do this: durationPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,(480 - HEIGHT OF PICKER  VIEW),width of screen,whatever)];

Comment: so you want it as low as possible but still showing the entire thing? I would just create a test picker (pass in 0 as the height and it'll default to normal size), then log its height after you show it somehow and then change your real picker's y origin to 480-whateveryougot. A quick google showed 215 was the default height but i'm not sure i'd trust it.